# Reference types and Inheritance issues

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

How come my compiler does not give me a warning or an error for this code:

```
class A {};
class B : public A{};
class C : public A{};
int main(int argc,char** args)
{
    B b;
    A& a = b;
    C c;
    a = c;
}
```

I would tend to think that this would result in the data being stored in the "b" variable is no longer of type "B" and is going to give me a bunch of problems....so why am I able to do this.

Comment: google "c++ slicing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = c;` performs assignment between the `A` part of `b`, and the `A` part of `c`.  The `B` and `C` parts (if any) of those objects are unmodified.

In general this is kind of dangerous as the `B` and `C` objects may not have been designed to have only their `A` sub-object assigned.  On [this thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54449/avoiding-object-slicing-within-abstractions-and-their-derivations) are various other suggestions for handling `operator=` in a class hierarchy.

Comment: So in other words my "b" variable is safe, but my "a" variable won't really act like I would expect it to?

Comment: @DarthRubik well I'm not sure how you expect the `a` to act

Answer (score 1):

See comments:

```
class A {};
class B : public A{};
class C : public A{};
int main(int argc,char** args)
{
    B b; // memory allocated for b to contain A+B
    A& a = b; // a is referencing A part of A+B
    C c; // memory allocated for c to contain A+C
    a = c; // a (A part of A+B) is overwritten from A part of A+C, c is sliced into a
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> How come my compiler does not give me a warning or an error?

A class has a copy constructor and assignment operator *by default* if they were not declared explicitly.  As a result, an instance of derived class (C) can be assigned to a variable of the base class type (A). This effect is known as [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

To prevent from this you can disable copy constructor and assignment operator in the base class:

```
class A 
{
   protected:
     A() = default;
     A(const A & source) = delete;
     A & operator = (const A & source) = delete;
};

 class B : public A{};
 class C : public A{};


 int main(int argc,char** args)
 {
    B b;
    A& a = b;
    C c;
    a = c;  // this will not compile
}
```